# Regex - Private subtags RFC5646

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp

Can someone please help me with a regex to pull out subtags from a RFC5646?

Example strings

```
en-us-x-test-test1 = test,test1
en-gb-x-test-test2 = test,test2
fr-x-test-test3 = test,test3
```

I'm using a QRegExp

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex here. Split your input by `-` then take the last two string and add a coma in between:

```
QString str = "en-us-x-test-test1";
QStringList list = str.split('-');
QString output = list.at(list.count()-2) + "," + list.at(list.count()-1);
```

Of course, you have to check for `list` length to avoid index error.